# What is the best and most concise way to Describe a Town and its Surroundings?

Tags: expressions, descriptive-grammar

I am creating a Text Based Game. When a character arrives in a Town, they are supposed to describe the town that they are in based on the buildings that are in the town. At the moment I have a very generic and bland description that looks something like this:

```
I just arrived in Ashville. I can see a Motel, a Bar and a Gun Store. I should look 
around for some supplies
```

At the moment I am just listing what they see in the town, but the description is lacking substance. I want the player to be able to create an Image in their head of what the town looks like. I have done some research, but most of the stuff I could find was much too detailed. Is there a way to describe a list of things whilst describing each of them with some detail?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an adverbial phrase to describe your surroundings.

> I just arrived in Asheville.  From left to right, I can see a motel, a
> bar, and a gun store. ...
>
> I just arrived in Asheville.  Nearest me I see a motel, a bar, and then a gun store ...

### Prepositions and adjectives are the only way to go, really.

> [...] arrived in Asheville.  The blue building to the left of me is a motel that faces an orange gun store situated next to a bar.

Comment: I will add that in. But it doesn't add enough depth. Those phrases don't really describe the individual locations themselves. Is there a way to not use a list separated by commas?

Comment: You specifically asked for something that wasn't much too detailed though...at least I thought? Something **concise**

Comment: I want a little bit of detail for each of them just not a paragraph is what I meant.

Comment: I suppose you could add anything from colors to smells to sounds to sensations really.  You could also group them into classes.

Comment: Then in your text based game you could type `Enter blue building`  or `Enter motel` assuming you describe the motel as a blue building

Comment: The main thing was, that I wanted to avoid having just a whole list of all the Buildings separated by commas. It felt unnatural.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: The building on the far left is blue.  The gun store is next to the red building.  The bar is not next to the yellow building. The motel is not next the store that sells guns....  ;-)